# Here server 503 response

Tags: here-api

I have created an application in python to simulate  a route and than extract speed limits from the Here data extension API. The route is long 3 days driving with 8 hours per day. When I run my application for the hole route I get in some point a 503 server response instead of a 200. If I try my application for the same route where I receive the bad server response but for shorter route (2 hours route) it works Ok. It looks like a bottleneck in the server.

```
  if self.country in WEE:
        url = "http://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?" + \
              "app_id=Gxxxxxx" + \
              "&app_code=xxxxxx" + \
              "&routemode=car&file=" + \
              "&regions=WEU&release=LATEST"
    else:
        url = "http://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?" + \
              "app_id=xxxxx" + \
              "&app_code=Qxxxxx" + \
              "&routemode=car&file=" + \
              "&regions=EEU&release=LATEST"

    if self.gps_source == 'gpx':
        response = self.connectPost(url, self.tmp_route_data, headers={"Content-type": "application/binary"})
    else:
        response = self.connectPost(url, self.tmp_route_data, headers={"Content-type": "text/csv"})


    if response.status_code != 200:
        message = 'Unable to build the route:<br>'
        message += 'unexpected response from HERE webservice.'
        raise RuntimeError(message)
    def connectPost(self, url, data, headers=None):
    return self.S.post(url, data=data, headers=headers , proxies = self.proxy_dict)
```

Comment: Can you share your API calls so we recreate this?

Comment: @leopectus I tried some more times and I found this is random. It occurs sometime in Belgium some times in Italy with different coordinates sent

Comment: I've noticed you're using the testing endpoint (CIT) instead of production. Can you remove the ".cit" from your URLs, try again and report back?

Comment: @leopectus The issue was resolved with the .cit in the URL , probably there was a server issue but now fixed . Thank you for your fast response.

Answer (score 0):

The Customer Integration Testing(CIT) should be used for low-volume integration and functional testing. HERE doesn't provide the SLA for CIT environment.

Both the Production and CIT environments are not designed to support sudden, unannounced high loads. If you need to do performance testing, [contact HERE](https://developer.here.com/contact-us) to discuss options.